# Why do my React routes no longer match when I configure Vite base?

Tags: react-router-dom, vite

Before setting `base` in my Vite configuration I can visit the app root at http://localhost:5173 without issue (renders 'Home'). When I add base though with a value of `/tools/evidence` and visit http://localhost:5173/tools/evidence as helpfully output by the Vite dev server it doesn't work - its instead renders the `<Not Found />` component.

I have put some debug in Not Found component and the paths are as expected. I can't figure out why they aren't resolving ...

Here are my routes ...

```
// ... imports ...

const NotFound = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  console.log(location)
  return <h1>Not Found</h1>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<div>Home</div>} />
          <Route
            path="/topics/*"
            element={
              <>
                <EditorRoutes />
                <PrintRoutes />
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/feedback" element={<FeedbackPage />} />
          <Route path="/accessibility" element={<Accessibility />} />
          <Route path="/cookies" element={<Cookies />} />
          <Route path="/algorithms" element={<Algorithms />} />
          <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

here is my `vite.config.ts`

```
// ... imports ...

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/tools/evidence',
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        postcssNesting
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just need to add a [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) to the router to match the "directory" the app is now running or being served from. This is to configure, or inform, the router to render all routes and links relative to *this* basename path, e.g `"/tools/evidence/feedback"`.

Example:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/tools/evidence">    // <-- router basename
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<div>Home</div>} /> // "/tools/evidence"
          <Route
            path="/topics/*"                        // "/tools/evidence/topics/*"
            element={
              <>
                <EditorRoutes />
                <PrintRoutes />
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/feedback"                        // "/tools/evidence/feedback"
            element={<FeedbackPage />}
          />
          <Route path="/accessibility" element={<Accessibility />} />
          <Route path="/cookies" element={<Cookies />} />
          <Route path="/algorithms" element={<Algorithms />} />
          <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Yes! Funny this isn't in the Vite docs ... for what its worth, you can use `basename={import.meta.env.BASE_URL}` instead of hard-coding